# Am I doing right when "sending" questions asking about rewrite rules to webmasters SE?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons

From time to time I find a question **purely** about [.htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.htaccess) rewrite rules in Triage review queue and vote to close such question with explicit reason like:

> This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Apache
>   administration and as such better fits to
>   [webmasters.stackexchange.com](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).

I thought that [webmasters.stackexchange.com](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) is site just for this sort of questions (webmasters' help do not mention this kind of questions explicitly but there's a lot of questions with rewrite rules topic there, so I would say they belong there, at least more than on SO).

Does it make sense to close these questions ? I think that users asking this sort of questions here (and it's a lot of them) might not know about webmasters SE. Am I doing right when closing them ?

Here is one [recent example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27798593/960757).

Comment: This has been answered before.  Believe me, I feel the same way (that they're off topic) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81032/are-htaccess-questions-ever-on-topic-at-so the general consensus is that the rules are a mini-language that programmers use. I think thats some boulsheet.

Comment: I guess it really depends... Problems occuring with `.htaccess` files might be due to regex errors, in which case you could argue this is the right place. In general I don't really mind, as `.htaccess` is used often next to programming websites.

Comment: @Will, thanks! That's my duplicate then (will delete this one in a while). Except this particular case there are other tags like e.g. [tag:r] on which many question fits better to http://stats.stackexchange.com/ and I think we could find more tags. Well, it seems there's no way out of this. I was thinking about assigning some sort of hints to certain tags in the sense of *Pssst! You've just added R tag and we have stats.stackexchange.com site which is specialized on statistics. Don't you want to check?* but I doubt someone would read or follow it.

Comment: @Kevin, that's even worse. There's already a bunch of .htaccess regex related questions on webmasters. But I will better stop closing them. Clicking the next button in the review queue is easier than closing with an explicit comment :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, those questions would be off-topic on Webmasters more than they are on Stack Overflow. Webmasters Stack Exchange is more about search engine optimization, domains and webhosting.

The article [What topics can I ask about here?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) in Webmasters Stack Exchange's Help Center actually refers to [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) for server configuration:

> There are some types of questions about running websites that don't belong on this site:
>
> (...)
>
> **System and network administration** -- [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) participants are much more likely to know the technical details on topics such as DNS and Apache configuration than people who answer questions here.

My personal opinion is therefore that they should belong on Server Fault, but [certain](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81032/are-htaccess-questions-ever-on-topic-at-so) [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6235/apache-configuration-htaccess-questions-esp-mod-rewrite-so-or-sf) questions (and also [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/39205/244357) by Jeff Atwood) suggest that they fit both SO and SF.

Comment: This categorization is so intuitive! /s